# Three.js - Export a texture as an image

Tags: image, three.js, export, webgl, rendering

I render some part of my scene and I use this as a texture on my object. But now I want to export this texture as an image. Any idea on that?

This is how I create my texture object:

```
frameTexture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter});
```

And I assign this texture on my material:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map:frameTexture.texture} );
```

And this is how I render it to the texture:

```
renderer.render(frameScene,frameCamera,frameTexture);
```

Now the question is how to save frameTexture as an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Render the image to the canvas then call toDataURL

```
renderer.render(sceneThatHasASingleQuadPlaneUsingFrameTexture, camera);
var dataURL = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
```

You can now do things with that dataURL like open a window

```
window.open(dataURL, "image");
```

Or make an image out of it

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = dataURL;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Send it to some server via XHR

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpReqeust();
xhr.open('PUT', 'https://myserverthatsavesimages.com', true);
xhr.send(dataURL);
...
```

Etc...

Answer (score 1):

Another easy solution is to render a scene having the texture as a background, that way you don't have to setup a camera to align it.

```
            const texture = /** load texture with textureloader **/
            
            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(400, 400);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight("rgb(255,255,255)", 1));

            // Here
            scene.background = texture;

            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);

            const imageURL = renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/png");
            var anchor = document.createElement("a");
            anchor.href = imageURL;
            anchor.download = "preview.png";
            anchor.click();

            anchor.remove();
            texture.dispose();
            renderer.domElement.parentElement?.removeChild(renderer.domElement);
            renderer.dispose();
```